# Why is The Mall (Westminster, London) pronounced like mawl?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, british-english

Why is [The Mall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mall,_London) pronounced differently even though it shares the same spelling as mall (shopping)?

Comment: I second what @z7sg said. As far as I can tell *shopping mall* and *pall mall* have the same pronunciation for *mall*.

Comment: How do -you- pronounce 'The Mall' as different from shopping 'mall'? In AmE, I pronounce them the same, so maybe BrE keeps them separate.

Comment: @Peter Shor I checked this on a BBC clip and they say /ˈmæl/, ie rhymes with pal not maul, likewise it's /ˌpæl ˈmæl/.  My comment was the result of confusion so I deleted it.  I think there is a lot of variation here.

Comment: For all the Americans who are probably totally confused by this question, Wikipedia says that both words in Pall Mall rhyme with *pal* and *gal.* This doesn't seem to be what the answers are saying, so there may be some variation in the pronunciation. Since *doll,* *ball* and *maul* all rhyme in AmE some of the subtleties of British pronunciation are lost on us.

Comment: Related: [How to properly pronounce 'mall'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12845/how-to-properly-pronounce-mall).

Comment: Alternatively why pronounce Shopping Mall as if it had a 'u' in it?

Comment: This is hardly the only instance of homographs which aren't homophones. Is there anything which motivates a particular interest in this one rather than the general issue?

Comment: @PeterShor ... The only pronunciation of "mall" different from "maul" I heard of (growing up in America), was a cigarette brand Pall Mall advertised on TV.  But all other uses of "mall" were pronounced the same as "maul".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The street in London actually comes from the French "*pêle-mêle*" meaning:

**From various online dictionaries**:

> 1. any old how, at random, chaotically
> 2. In a jumbled, confused manner; helter-skelter.
> 3. In frantic disorderly haste; headlong

The French pronunciation is likely where the "***a*** as in  **gal**" sound comes from.

When the portmanteau pall-mall/pell-mell sprouted up, according to Etymonline mall began meaning "*shaded walk serving as a promenade*". These walkways/alleys had become common places to play a game similar to croquet by the name of pall-mall. The street in question was originally such an alley.

At the same time usage began to drift from the French sounding "***a*** as in  **gal**" to a, perhaps more British, "***a*** as in  **ball**". When we finally got to the point where mall gained it's current meaning, the common usage was the latter but as the street is a proper name predating this change, so I assume it has simply kept the sounds originally ascribed to it.

Answer (score -1):

Pall Mall is a shortening of the Italian phrase Paglio Maglio (pronounced in English 'Pahlio Mahlio'), which is Italian for a game similar to croquet, which was played on that area.  Hence, the area was called Pall Mall.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).