# How do you pronounce 'Pall Mall'?

Tags: pronunciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is The Mall (Westminster, London) pronounced like mawl?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25724/why-is-the-mall-westminster-london-pronounced-like-mawl)

A few friends and I are playing Monopoly and are having an argument over how to pronounce the property 'Pall Mall'. Is it pronounced as 'Pal Mal' or 'Paul Maul'?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12845/how-do-you-properly-pronounce-mall 
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25724/why-is-the-mall-westminster-london-pronounced-like-mawl

Comment: What edition of Monopoly has *Pall Mall* on the board? There is no such property in the standard American version.

Comment: [The UK edition of Monopoly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopoly_%28game%29#UK_version) (what else?). [Here's the board.](http://thedabbler.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/monopoly.jpg).

Comment: There's a song in Andrew Lloyd Webber's musical *Cats* which rhymes "Pall Mall" with "shall".  So that's the pronunciation that sticks in my head, right or wrong.  This may be a bad sign, because there's another song in the musical which rhymes "Thames" with "aims", and even I, an American, know better than that.

Comment: Here in the Pacific NW United States, we say "Paul Maul". From other answers and comments, it seems to me that pronouncing it in whatever way seems right to you is the way to go.

Comment: @JSBᾶngs: "Good grief!", as Charlie Brown might say. Except being American, perhaps he wouldn't know the UK version either.

Comment: I am now amused by the idea that Darth Maul's first name might actually be Paul.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a Londoner I pronounce it *pal mal*, but I am much less consistent with the next street, The Mall, which I sometimes rhyme with *shall* and sometimes with *hall*.

The pronunciation has varied over time. Samuel Pepys wrote of the game as Pelemele (Diary 2nd April 1661) and the road as Pell Mell (Diary 1st May 1669).

Comment: I agree. Most (but not all) people (in Southern UK, at least) rhyme the shopping mall with "hall", but I've never heard that pronunciation with Pall Mall, even though the word "mall" is the same one, with the same etymology and meaning. It's just idiomatic usage based on the alliteration, I guess.

Answer (score 6):

Normal English pronunciation is Pal (as in friend) -  like shall

But it's named after a game in French Paille-maille, so 'upper-class' English pronunciation is sometimes Pel Mel.

Comment: The term "short a" can refer to at least three different sounds, so that's a pretty useless explanation.

Comment: Isn't the word for friend or buddy spelled pal not pall?

Comment: I'm not sure the *'upper-class' English pronunciation* is related to the fact that Pall Mall came from a French term. I think it's just another one of those standard vowel changes in "cut-glass" accents, like "hice" for "house".

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of variation. The cigarette brand was /pɛl mɛl/, just like the expression *pell-mell*, at least when I learned it in N. IL in the 40s and 50s. I later learned that some called it /pɔl mɔl/, which makes it a problematic word for Americans, because most people on the W coast have merged /a/ with /ɔ/, so what they say may well sound like /pal mal/ to others.

I must admit I've never heard it pronounced /pæl mæl/, which is what it would be if pronounced like *shall* /ʃæl/, though of course some pronounce *shall* the same as *shell* /ʃɛl/.

**Summary**: Decide on whatever name you like and stick with it. Everybody else does.

Comment: Yes, apparently the makers of the American cigarette brand, Pall Mall, _did_ mean for it to be pronounced such that both words rhyme with _bell_. To wit; [this 1955 commercial](http://youtu.be/Hr4duBBcCpA) and [this 1970 commercial](http://youtu.be/htktQhVrZT4).

Comment: The question is about the London place in Monopoly, not the American cigarette brand.

Comment: Americans wouldn't normally know that, and wouldn't know how to pronounce the RP name, even if they did.

Answer (score 2):

Both words rhyme with *shall*.